# SQL QUESTION - Difference between using special characters with '' or with "" in a query in PHP

Tags: php, sql, special-characters

In this php function I'm doing a query to tables that the name contain special characters like `$` so in php If I use `""` in the query the application thinks that the table name is a variable so it returns `Variable not found`.

**Exemple 1:**

```
$SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [table_name$1] 
        left join [table_name$2] as d on [Code] = d.[Code]
        where d.[Dimension Code] = 'NAT'
        and [Request Code] not like 'AC%'";
```

But if I use `''` in the query he thinks that everything inside `""` is a column so it returns `Invalide column Name` in this case `NAT`

**Exemple 2:**

```
$SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [table_name$1] 
        left join [table_name$2] as d on [Code] = d.[Code]
        where d.[Dimension Code] = "NATUREZA FUNC"
        and [Request Code] not like "AC%"';
```

Best way to escape this problem?
I now you can use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape them but there´s a lot of tables. I would like to now if it exists a more efficient way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was using prepared statements.

```
$SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [table_name$1] 
        left join [table_name$2] as d on [Code] = d.[Code]
        where d.[Dimension Code] = :nat
        and [Request Code] not like :ac';
```

And then use bind value

```
$result->bindValue(':nat', "nat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':year', $ac, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a really unclear database naming convention. Have you tried to use backticks ( ` ) to surround table references. See: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Also using prepared statements might be a better option.

Comment: This is SQL Server, not MySQL; and you can't use parameters for table names in prepared statements.